# Google Sheets List for 80/20 Rule

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of customer names in Column A and their total sales in Column B. Both columns are updated every week.

The list is ordered from most to least by total sales.

I want to use a QUERY or other formula that will show me a list of the customer names with the highest sales whose combined totals make up as close as possible to 80% of the grand total of the total sales column.

ChatGPT has failed me, so I've come to the experts. Please assist.

Here is a link to a dummy sheet if you'd like: [text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b7XMga_6baJhUGdkDz4PLDq-CopKe2yRPXtYlNAGZVE/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried variations of QUERY select sum, select avg, order by, limit and nothing worked. Tried SUMIF. The closest I could get was adding cumulative totals, but the cumulation didn't work properly and essentially only showed 4 customer names as making up 80% when it should've been 25 names.

Comment: "I tried variations of QUERY select sum, select avg, order by, limit and nothing worked." -- we don't want to repeat your failed attempts so we need to see your work so we can reproduce your issue and suggest fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(A2:A,lt(scan(,B2:B,lambda(a,c,a+c)),sum(B2:B*0.8)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a thing of beauty! Thank you so much. I was not familiar LT, SCAN or LAMBDA. Time to do some reading up!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(names,A2:A,
       sales,B2:B,
       cumul,SCAN(,SORT(sales,1,0),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c)),
       diff,ABS(0.8*SUM(sales)-cumul),
       seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(diff)),
       JOIN(" ",FILTER(names,seq<=XLOOKUP(MIN(diff),diff,seq)))))
```

We are calculating the cumulative sum, taking the absolute value of the difference between the cumulative sum and the 80% of the total sales to find the closest value and finally returning the appropriate names.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems a bit complex next to the other solution provided.

Comment: it doesn't seem like the other solution would work if the closest match is greater than or equal to the 80% of the total sales.