# How many top customers contribute to 80% of revenue?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out if there is a formula that can help me calculate "How many top customers contribute to 80% of revenue?".

I have a spreadsheet with Column A for the account names and Column B for their associated sales number.

Based on my online research most solutions recommended figuring out how many percent each account contributes to the total sales number. I have calculated this in Column C but unable to figure out a formula that would use this percentage to count the number of top accounts that would contribute to 80% of the total sales.

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e5E-kDzntCxQ4y0ay6zAuG6abivfUZRhANOZN1xj4j8/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: =arrayformula(sum(N(SCAN(0,C2:C40,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))<0.8)))+1

Comment: [similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76682272/5479575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers doesn't add up exactly to 80%. To include first value exceeding and adding to 82.69%:

```
=arrayformula(sum(N(SCAN(0,C2:C41,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))<0.8)))+1
```

To exclude exceeding value and adding to 79.76%:

```
=arrayformula(sum(N(SCAN(0,C2:C41,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))<0.8)))
```

Result:

[image]

Note that these formulas works if column `C` is sorted descending. Sort your range first:

```
=arrayformula(sum(N(SCAN(0,sort(C2:C41,1,),LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))<0.8)))+1
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e5E-kDzntCxQ4y0ay6zAuG6abivfUZRhANOZN1xj4j8/edit#gid=389954164) you may test; this directly refers to `Column_B` data*

```js
=counta(ifna(filter(B2:B,lte(scan(,B2:B,lambda(a,c,a+c)),sum(B2:B*0.8)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, awesome to see there are multiple approaches to this question.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach working directly on Col B (assumes that it will be sorted descending):

```
=count(filter(B2:B,sumif(row(B2:B),"<="&row(B2:B),B2:B)<=sum(B2:B)*0.8))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, awesome to see there are multiple approaches to this question.